# Laravel eloquent extending model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relational-database

I have default user model. Now I have another table for Administrators. Is there a way to return user fields (since admin is extending user) from admin model ? I found this example but its when admin_id is present in user model. I have one-to-one relation here.

```
class Admin extends User
{
    protected $table = 'users';

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope(function ($query) {
            $query->where('is_admin', true);
        });
    }
}
```

This is the example I found. I'm not sure how can I return user fields from my admin model when its on different table.

The point is I want to be able to do something like this (call methods from users):

```
Admin::first()->posts()
```

Where posts method is not on Admin class but on user class.

Edit:

To explain it better. I have two tables, users and admins. They are connected in one-to-one relationship so I can do something like this:

```
$admin = Admin::first();
$posts = $admin->user()->posts();
```

but since Admin should have all fields from users table and one more field from admins table I'm looking for a way to do this:

```
$admin = Admin::first();
$posts = $admin->posts();
```

I don't want to add admin or something to users table, I still want to use admins table since I will need more fields there later.

Comment: create query and put join or use relationship eloquent

Comment: @AlexanderVillalobos That won't achieve what I want to do

Comment: put your tables and relationships to understand what you want to do

Comment: @AlexanderVillalobos I edited first post

Comment: Do you have an admins table?  If so, why do you have this model using the users table?

Comment: do you need one table for solved you problem

Comment: @Devon I do, if you read the post I stated after the code this is an example for single table, but I have 2 tables

Comment: @AlexanderVillalobos Its easily done with one table, but I need two

Comment: How are your 2 user and admin models conformed

Comment: @AlexanderVillalobos I have one-to-one relationship

Comment: @Jimmy ok so that example really isn't applicable to your question since it's a completely different design.  Why can't you set up a user relationship?

Comment: @Devon I can, and I did. I can call do something like this:  `$admin = Admin::first();  $posts = $admin->user()->posts();`   but I'm trying to achieve `$admin->posts()` since admin have all the same fields like user + one extra field from admins table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both tables have an equal id, use a trait to define your relationships:

```
trait UserRelationships {
    public function posts() {
         return $this->hasMany(Post::class, 'user_id');
    }
}

class Admin {
    use UserRelationships;
}

class User {
    use UserRelationships;
}
```

You'll just have to be sure to explicitly declare the foreign key name in the relationship.

You could also extend the User model and override the `$table` property but this may present problems for various reasons since `User` properties exist on the user relationship and not on the `Admin` model.

Comment: That should work for relationships, but  do you think that there is a more unversal approach here ? For example then I will need to create trait for UserMethods so when I add a method to user its reflected in admin class. Extending the user class would be ideal, but if thats not possible then your approach would be the only other solution

Comment: I updated my answer with my concerns for that.  It's possible but you'd have to change a lot in the Admin model to support that since all the user fields would exist on the relationship and not the admin's attributes.  You'd need a mutator for every user field essentially is the way I'd tackle it.

Comment: @Jimmy you may consider the single table approach if you don't foresee more differentiation in fields later on.  You could also just have an admin relationship on User instead.

Comment: There will be one or more additional fields, but I also want some methods to be admin specific, that is why I need Admin class. I don't really want to bloat my user model with something like ban method or so...